# How to replay .log files faster?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello, Is it possible to replay .log files (generated for the vrc) faster? It is veeery slow when i replay here.. actually slower than the run itself (that got an 0.25 real time factor average).

Regards,

LR

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2831/how-to-replay-.log-files-faster?/) by [Luis Filipe Rossi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/55/luis-filipe-rossi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-05-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I would filter the .log files first then playback, see if that helps. The bottom of this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.7/state_log_filtering) shows how to use the hz filter. Note that filtering a large log file can take a while though.

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2013-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Luis Filipe Rossi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/55/luis-filipe-rossi/) on 2013-05-15**:
I did it.. now it is super fast.. but actuallly faster than it should be. Anyway to control the gazebo update rate so it will run in 1s/s rate?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-07-30**:
Not yet, but that feature is in the works.

**Comment by [NickDP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/964/nickdp/) on 2014-09-26**:
Has this feature been implemented yet? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Running the raw (binary) state.log is extremely slow.  If you run the "mkqual" filtered logs for VRC, then it is extremely fast.

Of course that means you have to wait several hours to process the binary log, but at least it's easy to verify the filtered text log.

---

Originally posted by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) with karma: 298 on 2013-05-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Luis Filipe Rossi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/55/luis-filipe-rossi/) on 2013-05-15**:
Thank you for the help. I was already filtering using the tutorial as advised iche033. I oppened the mkqual.bash and it uses the same command that i was using. Any advice on how to get a 1s/s update rate when playing the log?